# the_author_posts_link css class

Tags: php, css, author

Currently I'm styling as project where I need to add a custom CSS to `the_author_posts_link()`.

I want to add the class "blog-link" with the `the_author_posts_link()` . How do I add a css class to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `the_author_posts_link` filter to add the custom `blog-link` class:

```
/**
 * Add the 'blog-link' class to the output of the_author_posts_link()
 */
add_filter( 'the_author_posts_link', function( $link )
{
    return str_replace( 'rel="author"', 'rel="author" class="blog-link"', $link );
});
```

Comment: Just be careful doing something like this because if another plugin or the theme has already done something similar you will end up with 2 class attributes. I would recommend using strpos to first check if class=" exists and if so insert your classname there.